# How to map multiple different request bodies in to same POJO using a configuration file

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, http-post, mapping

I have different post request bodies like follows:

```
{
   "name": "US",  
   "amount": "1234"    
}

{
   "fullName": "US",  
   "transAmount": "1234"    
}
```

I have created a java filter to modify those request bodies in my spring boot application. I want to convert them in to an uniform format in order to make all the request bodies can be mapped in to same POJO.

Eventually "name" and "fullName" shold be mapped to name,
"amount" and "transAmount" should be mapped to amount. How can I achieve this?

I already have an answer:

```
@JsonAlias({"name", "fullName"})
private String name;
```

But I want to achieve this using a configuration file. Then just changing the configuration file I can add/remove mapping values. How can I do the same thing using configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution. (I`m sure there are might be alternative ones)

I guess you would need to override default `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`'s behaviour, and implement your custom logic in `findPropertyAliases(..)` method.

Your (custom) introspector can then be registered with `ObjectMapper#setAnnotationIntrospector` call.

```
public void tryIt() throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomAnnotationIntrospector());

    YourBean yourBean = objectMapper.readValue("{\"altField\": \"abc\"}", YourBean.class);
    System.out.println(yourBean.getField());
}

static class YourBean
{
    @JsonAliasConfigPath("/some/where")
    private String field;

    public String getField()
    {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }
}


@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
        ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
@interface JsonAliasConfigPath
{

    String value();

}


class CustomAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector
{
    @Override
    public List<PropertyName> findPropertyAliases(Annotated member)
    {
        CustomAliasConfig.JsonAliasConfigPath atConfigPath = _findAnnotation(member, CustomAliasConfig.JsonAliasConfigPath.class);

        if (atConfigPath != null)
        {
            // here is your config file
            String value = atConfigPath.value();
            String setterName = member.getName();
            // read&return aliases for setterName
            // return youListOfAliases;

            // let`s assume it turns your member should be expected as "altField"
            return Arrays.asList(PropertyName.construct("altField"));
        }

        return super.findPropertyAliases(member);
    }
}
```